# Get the selected text (not selected value) of an asp:dropdownlist in code behind using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I need to read in the code behind the selected text (not the value) in the dataTextField of a dropdownlist that is nested in a FormView.

Here is my DDL:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL1" dataTextField="name" DataValueField="IDname" CausesValidation="True" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
      DropDownList DDL1 = FV1.FindControl("DDL1") as DropDownList;
      SQL3.UpdateParameters["ddlparam"].DefaultValue = DDL1.SelectedValue;
     // Possible to get the text corresponding to the selectedValue?  
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to get the text in the dataTextField corresponding to the selected value. Possible? and How?

Comment: Use DDL1.SelectedItem.Text

Answer (score 4):

Grab the text of the selected item with:

```
DDL1.SelectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for `DDL.SelectedItem.Text` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dzda081(v=vs.110).aspx)